# manterner scroll al retornar a la pagina principal

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Necesitaria alguna ayuda con esto, estoy haciendo una pokedex, cuando clikeas el pokemons te lleva a otra screen donde te muestra mas caracteristicas, luego hay una boton de return, mi problema es que al volver a la pagina principal no conservo el scrool y me vuelve al incio de la pagina. Estoy usando react-router-dom-v6. Lo intente con esto pero no funciona

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

    <button 
        className='main__button'  
        type='text'
        onClick={ () => navigate( -1 ) }
    >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar `queryParams` o pasar directamente el `id` del `tag` en la ruta como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 3ms;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="sect-1">
  section 1 ==>
  <a href="#sect-3">section 3</a>
</section>
<section id="sect-2">
  section 2 ==>
  <a href="#sect-1">section 1</a>
</section>
<section id="sect-3">
  section 3 ==>
  <a href="#sect-2">section 2</a>
</section>
```